# Dictionary in python doesn't show correct response

Tags: python, dictionary

The code needs to say the numbers that are in the dictionary with letters and if there is no such number it shows ! ,
 My problem is that it works with only one number but when I write multiple numbers it shows the ! message , 
please help !

```
phone = [input("Number : ")]

numbers  = {
    "1" : "one",
    "2" : "two",
    "3" : "three",
    "4" : "four"
}

output = ""
for ch in phone:
    output += numbers.get(ch, "!") + " "
print(output)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're making `phone` a list of 1 item with a string with

```
phone = [input("Number : ")]
```

You'll want either

```
phone = list(input("Number : "))
```

to unwrap each character into a list, or just

```
phone = input("Number : ")
```

since you can just as well iterate over a string.